# Good flow chart (or bpmn) visualization libraries integrated with GWT/Vaadin?

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I'm working on project using GWT (with Vaadin) and I'm looking for a good, preferably, integrated flow chart library. The library can be commerical and preferrably is integrated with Vaadin.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with mx-graph gwt wrapper with vaadin:

http://forum.jgraph.com/questions/4390/using-mxgraph-with-vaadin
http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual.html#2.2.2.1